# pass values from RecyclerView to view it in activity

Tags: java, android

I need to pass data from `RecyclerView` to `GalleryActivity` class to view image and 2 texts by clicking on `RecyclerView`. I followed [this tutorial](https://androidjson.com/android-json-parsing-recyclerview-image-text/). It is warking good but I want to open image and text in another activity. Can someone help?

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
        if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
            //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
            RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,GalleryActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title",title);
            bundle.putString("url",url);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    }
});
```

And the `GalleryActivity` class

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        setTitle(title);
        TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image_description);
        desc.setText(title);
    }
}
```

activity_gallery:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_description"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Canada"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently? From a quick glance, you appear to use the Intent correctly to pass the data to a new activity. The only piece left is to use the url to load the image.

Comment: Could you show the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in very easy way, it can be implemented by many ways. One i am posting for you. This is an sample of Adapter class, in which you need to pass `Context` for further use.

If you have `Context` available in your adapter you can start an activity with your bundle like.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
                    String s = list.get(getAdapterPosition()); // here you will get current item
                    intent.putExtra("key", s);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Here is complete code that you need to integrate as your adapter.

```
public class AdapterDemo extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDemo.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
                    String s = list.get(getAdapterPosition()); // here you will get current item
                    intent.putExtra("key", s);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }



    public AdapterDemo(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_nothing_to_display, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String s = list.get(position);
        // TODO: 4/29/2018  your code here
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list.size();
    }


    public void insertItemInList(String beanChat) {
        if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(beanChat);
        notifyItemInserted(list.size() - 1);
    }


    public void insertItemsInList(ArrayList<String> myList) {
        if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String beanChat : myList) {
            insertItemInList(beanChat);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list;
    }

    public void clearList() {
        if (list == null) return;
        list.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: First thank u about your comment , can you please edit my code  or the code in the tutorial please thank u again

Comment: Did you provide all code, you just provided a part of your code. so i posted an sample. you should post your recycler view adapter class, so i can change it.

Answer (score -1):

using static you can do this.As we know the static data means class level data so we can access them by class name without creating class object.So when you need to pass value to activity view from recycler view adapter make some empty static variable on recycler view adapter and then assign value to them when you need to pass value and then access them from activity like `MyRecViewAdapter.myValue`

Comment: Using `static` class variables to pass data to another activity is dangerous. Using an Intent to pass the data is preferred.

Comment: Because the Android System may destroy an activity which is not active at any time. More generally, `static` is intended when you have data which you need to share between all instances of a class. When you make `myValue` static, you are saying that all instances of `MyRecViewAdapter` have the same value. Using `static` to share data with other classes incorrectly uses static. There are other Object Oriented techniques to solve that problem.